# Entity framework StackOverflowException in constructor call? Very strange

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I generated an EDMX file in Visual Studio 2010 and did some work on it. It's a quite large architecture I'm working with here. It has worked just fine, and then all of a sudden, without changing anything, now when I start it, I am receiving an error when it is trying to instantiate the ModelContainer (my ObjectContext) class.

The error is received on the following line:

```
public ModelContainer() : base("name=ModelContainer", "ModelContainer")
```

In other words, the constructor of the actual EDMX class.

The error is a typical StackOverflowException. I'm unable to fetch details about the inner exception as well, since it can't when in a stack-overflow state.

Any clue?

Comment: Check whether it’ll allow you to break within an `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` handler. If it does, you could fetch more information about the inner exception and the state of the stack.

Comment: Although you can't see the inner exception, you should be able to view the call stack. From this, you may be able to identify a path of recursion (the same series of calls repeating over and over) that is leading to the overflow.

Comment: Jay, that worked. Post it as a solution, and I'll mark it as such. You deserve the credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can debug this using the call-stack window. Probably, the solution will become obvious.

Comment: You might also want to make sure that you enable display of non-user code.